# Will a running process be terminated if my computer shuts down while connected to an EC2 instance via session manager?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, session-manager

I am using Windows and connecting to a Linux EC2 instance via Session Manager.

The instance has an S3 bucket mounted, I am running a heavy decompression operation which writes output to the S3 bucket, and this could take over a day to complete. (**Clarifying: This operation is taking place in the EC2 instance**)

I have not used session manager before so I am unsure about this: If my Windows PC shuts down, will the decompression operation also get cancelled or will it keep running as long as the instance is active?

Comment: An answer  to a different question but probably helpful as well in your scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26246546/6873438

Comment: This is unfortunately not related to it. The question you're linking is about keeping a node process running, in that case the process stopped running simply because it was the way node was designed back then. For my situation, my concern is whether the process at the instance level will be suddenly terminated if my local computer shuts down